# AttributeError: 'InputStream' object has no attribute 'decode' using pandas_read_xml to flatten xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, azure-functions

I'm still a beginner to this, but I will try to explain my problem as coherently as I can.

In case you're not familiar with Azure Cloud programming, I have a "blob trigger" where this script runs or triggers when a file is uploaded into a container in Azure. When this script triggers it passes an InputStream object to the function:

```py
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

My problem lies when passing this InputStream object to a pandas_read_xml method.

```py
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

df = pdx.read_xml(myblob)

df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)
```

The goal here is to pass an xml file to a dataframe and then flatten the xml so that I can get all of the data inside of the XML. This works when the file can be found locally on my own machine, but when I go to pass the InputStream object "myblob" to the read_xml() method I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'InputStream' object has no attribute 'decode'

I've also tried downloading the blob to memory and pass that to the method like so:

```py
#Connect to storage container/ download blob
container_str_url = 'REDACTED'
container_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_str_url)
blob client accessing specific blob
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob= blob_name)
#download blob into memory
stream_downloader = blob_client.download_blob()
stream = BytesIO()
stream_downloader.readinto(stream)

df = pdx.read_xml(stream)

df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)
```

but this also doesn't work. Any idea on how I can use this library within this context? I think it works perfectly based off what I'm seeing whenever I use it on local files, I would love to find a way to use it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'InputStream' object has no attribute 'decode'

In General, this error will occur because of decoding the already decoded string. If your Azure Functions Python Version is **3.X**, then no need to decode.

If it is throwing the decode error, there is some error in datatype of that object so you should do both encoding and decoding for that input stream object `stream_downloader` you have defined in the code.

Encoding should be done in UTF-8 format or any other required format like binary, etc.

Also, **`function.json`** should contain the datatype of the input stream object (blob file) in Azure Functions Python project.

**Sample Code Snippet**:

```
{
      "name": "inputblob",
      "dataType": "binary",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "blobdata/blobfile.xml",
      "connection": "blobcontainer_conn_str"
    },
```

[image]